# passing structure object as parameter to a thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

This code runs successfully and MQStruct constructor initialized the values as well, I can see in ExecuteThread function but in TestFunction, I get the garbage values for MQStruct.

I am passing address of struct "&MQStructObj" to _beginthreadex for parameters and This is the problem I guess

```
struct MQStruct {
    MQStruct()
    {
        pointer=NULL;
        serviceName=NULL;
        durability=0;
        msgType=0;
        msgHeader=0;
        msgId=NULL;
        payload=NULL;
        payloadSize=0;
        ttl=0;
        priority=0;
    }

    void* pointer;
    wchar_t *serviceName; 
    int durability; 
    int msgType; 
    int msgHeader; 
    wchar_t *msgId; 
    wchar_t *payload; 
    int payloadSize; 
    int ttl; 
    int priority;
};


int ExecuteThread() {

    HANDLE   heartBeatThread;
    unsigned int hbThreadID;
    int result = 0;

        MQStruct MQStructObj;
        MQStructObj.pointer=this;

    heartBeatThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0 , &TestFunction, &MQStructObj, 0/*CREATE_SUSPENDED*/, &hbThreadID);


    if ( heartBeatThread == 0 )
    {
        result = -1;
        LogEvent(DEBUG_LOG,0, "Fail to create thread");
    }


    CloseHandle(heartBeatThread);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You guessed correctly.

You're passing the address of a local variable to your thread-proc-startup, then leaving scope (and destroying the object in the process). References to this object in your thread proc are there-after undefined behavior.

Dynamically allocate one with `new` and let the thread proc `delete` it.

Comment: Do you mean like this MQStruct* MQStructObj=new MQStruct();

Comment: @Shahzad correct. Just make sure to `delete` it, most likely *in your thread proc*, when finished with it. Also, I noticed you're not doing anything with any of your other members in that object. If this is because you stripped out all but the relevant code here before posting, *thank you*. If not, you may as well just pass `this` as the thread param (which is very common in C++ architectures using threads, btw).

Comment: I am using all elements but just for post to make it shorter I showed only one property. Thanks :)

Comment: @Shahzad Very well then. And again, *thank you* for stripping down your code to root out the issue. It made finding the problem very quick, as you could probably tell.

Answer (score 2):

`MQStructObj` is declared on the stack so will go out of scope and potentially be overwritten as soon as `ExecuteThread` completes.

If you want to use a stack object here, you'll need to add some synchronisation to allow your new thread to copy from `MQStructObj` before `ExecuteThread` returns.

Alternatively, normally preferably, you could allocate `MQStructObj` dynamically and leave the new thread to clean it up at its leisure

```
MQStruct* MQStructObj = new MQStruct();
MQStructObj->pointer=this;
heartBeatThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0 , &TestFunction, MQStructObj, 0, &hbThreadID);
if ( heartBeatThread == 0 ) { // error
    delete MQStructObj;
    result = -1;
}
// ownership of MQStructObj transferred to new thread
```